# Colocar um valor default no binding.value Vue Directive

Tags: vue.js

Gente to criando uma directive simples e queria saber como coloco um valor se o `binding.value` for `undefined` de uma forma mais simples, bem parecido como o Vue Component em que pode setar o defalut value?

Exemplo:

```
Vue.directive('color', {
    bind: function (el, binding) {
        var prop = binding.value,
            color = prop.color

            if(color == undefined) color = '#FFFFFF'

        el.style.backgroundColor = color
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma mais objetiva e direta você pode resolver assim:

```
Vue.directive('color', {
    bind: function (el, binding) {
        var prop = (binding.value || { color: '#FFFFFF' }),
            color = prop.color

        // Não vai mais precisa dessa checagem.
        //if(color == undefined) color = '#FFFFFF'

        el.style.backgroundColor = color
    }
})
```